# Firebase messaging service worker "firebase-messaging-sw.js" gets opened when click on FCM Push Notification

Tags: javascript, web, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a website [www.hotshots123.com](http://www.hotshots123.com).
I have implemented Firebase Messaging and sending Push Messages from Firebase Messaging Console.
As per the documentation at   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive, I have added Firebase messaging service worker firebase-messaging-sw.js.

I have added eventListener to handle click event on Notification.

Here  is the code.

service worker file  firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
// Following values are changed for security purpose

firebase.initializeApp( {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDfNp4Q3a-aXMItfgt4ZJlDc",
    authDomain: "hotshoaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: 'https:ebaseio.com',
    projectId: "hots069",
    storageBucket: "hotppspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "223156569",
    appId: "1:269:web:c4d1",
    measurementId: "G-CXKE"
});


const messaging = firebase.messaging();
let  link ="";

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    //console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    title = payload.notification.title;
    body = payload.notification.body;
    link =  payload.data.link;
    imgLink = payload.data.imgLink;

    console.log('[Received background message ',title+"  "+body+"  "+link );
    const notificationTitle = title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: body,
        icon: imgLink,
        image: imgLink
    };
    
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);

    event.notification.close();
    // This looks to see if the current is already open and
    // focuses if it is
    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
        type: "window"
    }).then((clientList) => {
        for (const client of clientList) {
            if (client.url === '/' && 'focus' in client)
                return client.focus();
        }

        if (clients.openWindow)
            return clients.openWindow(link);
    }));
});
```

I am able to send notification and handle the click event on notification successfully.

What I am expecting : When I or user click on Notification, Link should get opened in browser.

The problem is when I click on Notification (either on Laptop or Mobile) service worker file  "firebase-messaging-sw.js" gets opened in browser(and not the link).

See Screenshot
[image]

I went through the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive  properly and added code as per the documentation. Tried different option from Internet.